# Bizzare JFileChooser situation, the right click menu text is blank

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I am using a bare bones JFileChooser on Redhat 6 with the code:

```
JFileChooser testFileChooser = new JFileChooser("Test");
testFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
```

The JFileChooser works as expected. In the file selection area, if I right click, I get a dialog with three rows, one with an arrow. There is no text describing what the rows does. The first row switches between list and detail views. The second row appears to do nothing and the third row creates a new folder. When I googled about this problem there appears to be no way to access or inspect this right-click popup dialog of the JFileChooser. I do not understand how it could break in the first place like this. I need ideas for how to fix or workaround this problem please.

Comment: FYI the text for each of those menu items is supposed to say, 'View', 'Refresh', and 'New Folder'. I don't know why it might not show up. Perhaps some language file missing or wrong?

Comment: How do I verify that my language file is not missing?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps try uninstalling and reinstalling Java?

Comment: Make sure you're running the code from within the context of the EDT. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am very confident that I am on the EDT when I right click. I cannot figure out how to set a breakpoint in the debugger to prove it. Is there a way I can prove it that I am on the EDT when I right click?

Comment: The right-click event itself couldn't possibly be dispatched anywhere other than the event dispatch thread. The question is are you on the EDT when you create and show the JFileChooser? Use `EventQueue.isDispatchThread()` to check.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a fix/workaround!

JFileChooser uses a FilePane internally, which uses the JFileChooser's getComponentPopupMenu as it's context menu. However, because that returns null, it creates its own.

The text on the labels are gotten from the UIManager, with UIManager.getString calls. For some reason, the UIManager is returning empty strings.

So, we just have to set the strings in the UIManager manually.

If you make these calls before creating the file chooser, that'll fix it.

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewActionLabelText", "Details");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewActionLabelText", "List");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.viewMenuLabelText", "View");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText", "Refresh"));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderActionLabelText", "New Folder");
```

I realize this is 4 years late, but I hope this helps.